# Guardar valor de select desplegable en php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Tengo un problema con un select (tipo combo o dropdown), allí cargo con php una serie de categorías, el tema es que por un error de armado de la base original y a que las categorías no pueden ser mas de 20/30, siempre se llaman por su campo categoría (texto) y no por su ID. En este caso, cargo el select tanto en value como en el texto a mostrar con un string o nombre de la categoría, ya que la consulta para mostrar los artículos de la categoría la hago por un like.

Elijo la categoría, hago una consulta, se recarga la pagina con la nueva consulta, y pierdo la ubicación del select, vuelve al primer elemento, aunque necesito quede exactamente en la categoría que se eligió último.
Alguna idea de como hacerlo ?
Les muestro la parte del código :

```html
                    <form id="guarda_combo" method="POST" action="categoria.php">
                        <span> Seleccione una Categoría </span>
                        <select id="combo_categorias" name="cat" onchange="location.href='categoria.php?num=' + this.value +'1';">
                <?php
                    if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $consulta)) {
                        /* obtener array asociativo */
                        while ($filas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            $idCategoria=$filas['idCategoria'];
                            $descCategoria=$filas['descCategoria'];                                
                            echo "<option value='".$descCategoria."'>" . $descCategoria."</option>";
                         }      
                   ?>        
                        </select> 
                    </form>
```

---

sanzante, por una cuestion de diseño, quizás no muy bueno, al elegir una categoria del select voy categoria.php que es donde tomo el valor enviado y proceso la vista. Ahi mismo igualé la categoria con una variable de session llamada "cat_elegida". 
Adapté la solución a lo siguiente :

```html
                        while ($filas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            $idCategoria=$filas['idCategoria'];
                            $descCategoria=$filas['descCategoria'];
                            $currentcategoria=$_SESSION["cat_elegida"];
//                            echo "<option value='".$descCategoria."'>" . $descCategoria."</option>";
                            if ($descCategoria == $currentCategoria)
                                {
                                $selected = 'selected="selected"';
                                echo "<option $selected value='".$descCategoria."'>" . $descCategoria."</option>";
                                }else{
                            echo "<option value='".$descCategoria."'>" . $descCategoria."</option>";
                            }
                            }
```

por algun error o razón no me funciona,

Comment: Ajax sería una opción. Para no recargar la página. Y mantener la selección.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que indicar en el HTML generado cual es la opción seleccionada. Para ello debes usar la propiedad `selected`. Por ejemplo:

```
<select name="selector">
  <option>A</option>
  <option selected="selected">B</option>
  <option>C</option>
  <option>D</option>
  <option>E</option>
</select>
```

En tu caso:

```
<?php
  if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $consulta)) {
      /* obtener array asociativo */
      while ($filas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $idCategoria=$filas['idCategoria'];
          $descCategoria=$filas['descCategoria'];
          $selected = "";                                
          if ($descCategoria === $currentCategoria) {
            $selected = 'selected="selected"';                                
          }
          echo "<option $selected value='".$descCategoria."'>" . $descCategoria."</option>";
      }      
?>
```

En el bucle si `$descCategoria` es igual a `$currentCategoria` se añade un `selected="selected"` al `option` actual.

Obviamente tendrás que fijar en `$currentCategoria` la categoría que estaba seleccionada en el formulario. Para ello tendrás que consular el array con los datos del form, normalmente `$_POST`.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes mandar una variable adicional y verificar, si existe... marcas como selected la que sea igual al imprimir el select.

```
<form id="guarda_combo" method="POST" action="categoria.
    <span> Seleccione una Categoría </span>
    <select id="combo_categorias" name="cat" onchange="location.href='categoria.php?num=' + this.value +'1'&actual='+this.value+';">
    <?php
          if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $consulta)) {
          /* obtener array asociativo */
              while ($filas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                  $idCategoria=$filas['idCategoria'];
                  $descCategoria=$filas['descCategoria'];                                
                  echo "<option value='".$descCategoria."' ".(isset($_GET['actual']) ? 'selected' : "").">" . $descCategoria.</option>";
              }
          }      
    ?>        
    </select> 
</form>
```

Al hacer `(isset($actual) ? 'selected' : "")` el verifica si existe `$actual` imprime selected, sino lo deja en blanco.

Comment: Buenísimo, funcionó !  por desgracia se complicó otra cosa .. Yo ahí conservo el valor del select , el problema es que paso a otra pantalla, al volver se refresca, me toma el ultimo valor del select, pero como tengo que ejecute la vista a partir del onchange ... y el valor del select no varía , no me refresca la consulta.  Alguna idea para manejar esto ? Graciassss